# Find Replace of Greek characters in Excel using VBA macro

Tags: excel, replace, unicode, find, character

I'm attempting to make a VBA macro to help me clean up electronics parts descriptions in an Excel bill of materials. It deletes excess spaces with Trim and shortens several long words. However, I can't figure out how to properly find / replace for a Greek symbol like Omega. The character code numbers don't seem to work. *I'm not sure if I'm using ChrW wrong or what the issue is.*

On another forum it was suggested to me that I needed to add MatchByte:=True into the code, but it doesn't seem to help or hinder.

Via much experimentation I've discovered a solution to part of this problem. It turns out that the µ - MICRO SIGN (Unicode and ASCII (hex) character code 00B5 and also ASCII (decimal) character code 181) works perfectly fine when you just paste its symbol into the VBA find / replace code. The macro then find / replaces it perfectly.

I am *perplexed* as to why the Greek mu, omega, and rho symbols don't work that way though.

μ - GREEK SMALL LETTER MU (Unicode (hex) character code 03BC)

Ω - GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA (Unicode (hex) character code 03A9)

Ω - OHM SIGN (Unicode (hex) character code 2126)

ρ - GREEK SMALL LETTER RHO (Unicode (hex) character code 03C1)

```
Sub DescriptionFix()
'
' DescriptionFix Macro
' Shortens Description by replacing long words and removes excess spaces from the Description Column
' Select a column or a portion of a column to run this macro on
'
    Dim r As Range

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For Each r In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        r.Value = .Trim(r.Value)
    Next r
    Selection.Replace What:="RESISTOR", Replacement:="RES", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:="ChrW(2126)", Replacement:="OHM", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, MatchByte:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="ChrW(03A9)", Replacement:="OHM", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:="TRANSISTOR", Replacement:="TRANS", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="CRYSTAL", Replacement:="XTAL", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="CAPACITOR", Replacement:="CAP", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="µ", Replacement:="u", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:="ChrW(03BC)", Replacement:="u", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        MatchByte:=True, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="ChrW(03C1)", Replacement:="p", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        MatchByte:=True, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:="TANTALUM", Replacement:="TANT", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="CERAMIC", Replacement:="CER", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="INDUCTOR", Replacement:="IND", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="FERRITE", Replacement:="FERR", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="GREEN", Replacement:="GRN", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="BLACK", Replacement:="BLK", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="YELLOW", Replacement:="YEL", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="VOLTAGE", Replacement:="VOLT", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="REGULATOR", Replacement:="REG", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="CONNECTOR", Replacement:="CONN", LookAt:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="TRANSFORMER", Replacement:="XFMR", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use quotes around character codes (i.e. use `ChrW(03C1)` instead of `"ChrW(03C1)"` otherwise you are literally looking for `ChrW(03C1)` and not the character it represents

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad 

I tried -

Selection.Replace What:=ChrW(03A9), Replacement:="OHM", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

but I got an error message 
"Compile error: 
Expected: list separator or )" which appears to be some sort of incorrect syntax error.

Comment: The syntax error is likely part of a typo. Keep in mind you still might need to use `MatchByte` as suggested to you in your vbforums question here http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?884011-Find-and-Replace-for-Greek-Characters&p=5455515&viewfull=1#post5455515

Comment: Try using the decimal instead of the hex value `ChrW(937)` instead of `ChrW(03A9)`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Oh wow, that totally works. Where do I look up these codes? 937 isn't showing in the Insert > Symbol chart when I select Omega? If I select it and then select "ASCII (decimal)" it just disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use quotes around character codes (i.e. use `ChrW(03C1)` instead of `"ChrW(03C1)"` otherwise you are literally looking for the string `ChrW(03C1)` and not the character it represents
2. VBA expect the code to be decimal and not hex (i.e. `ChrW(937)` instead of `ChrW(03A9)`
3. If you need to convert the codes from hex to decimal, you can use any one of several converters or lookup tables online. Something like https://unicodelookup.com/

Comment: Thanks for your help!! ChrW(8486) - the Ohm symbol - and ChrW(937) - the capital Omega - both work, though oddly enough, both remove all Omega symbols even if one is the Ohm symbol and the other is the capital Omega. And I very much appreciate the Unicode lookup website link, that helped me out :)

Comment: `ChrW(&H03C1)` should work for a hexadecimal constant.